# Python & Selenium: Find element by text in span class

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, automation

I'm trying to find an element, but it doesn't have any ID nor anything else. HTML looks basically like this:

```
<div class="item_select">
   <span class="item_selection_number">A
</span>
</div>

<div class="item_select">
   <span class="item_selection_number">B
</span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find the B element on every page, but its position varies every time, so I can't use `span[1]` or `n-th child(1)`. How can I do this?

Comment: We need a larger context to figure out robust way. Please post more of your HTML. That said, you could try matching text.

Comment: Iterate over all the `span` tags and check the text.

Comment: Get all of the item_selection_number then check the innerText

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too broad. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this xpath selector, its the best way when selecting text

```
//span[@class='item_selection_number'][contains(text(),'B')]
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped.